# Error occurred :Http failure during parsing for [URL] while calling http Post from angular 7

Tags: angular

I am trying to post data from a form into my rest backend server, the data is getting posted, but httpclient.post returns an error response ' Error occurred :Http failure during parsing for [URL]'.

I have tried the fixes suggested by the similar questions, but did not find any suitable one for angular 7

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as UrlConstants from './urls';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { Book } from './book/book';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
};
//import { RequestOptions, Request, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {
  private _getBooksUrl: string = UrlConstants.BOOKS_URL;
  private _postBooksUrl: string = UrlConstants.POST_BOOK_URL;
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getAllBooks(): Observable<Book[]> {
    console.log(this._getBooksUrl);
    return this._http.get<Book[]>(this._getBooksUrl)
      .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

  addBook(book: Book) {
    let body = JSON.stringify(book);
    return this._http.post<Book>(this._postBooksUrl, body, httpOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandlerPost));
  }
  errorHandler(errorHandler: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<Book[]> {
    return throwError(errorHandler.message || "server error");
  }
  errorHandlerPost(errorHandler: HttpErrorResponse) {
    return throwError(errorHandler.message || "server error");
  }
}
```

bookcomponent.ts

```js
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
  public books = [];
  public errorMessage;
  book = new Book();
  constructor(private _bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBooks();
  }
  getBooks():void{
    this._bookService.getAllBooks()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.books = data;
        console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
        this.errorMessage = error
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }

  addBook():void{
    this._bookService.addBook(this.book)
    .subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log(response)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("Error occurred :" + error);
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post `UrlConstants` too?

Comment: What httpOptions pass in the post?

Comment: Can you please post any error that occurred in the console too

Comment: const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json')
};

Comment: Error occurred :Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/create

Comment: this is the error that gets logged in the console

Comment: urlConstants:export const BOOKS_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/getBooks';
export const POST_BOOK_URL = 'http://localhost:8080/BookAPI/api/create';

Comment: it would be great if you add this code to your question instead of posting it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this first. Let me know if you have already tried this approach

Change `return this._http.post<Book>(this._postBooksUrl, body, httpOptions)`
  to `return this._http.post<Book>(this._postBooksUrl, body, {responseType: 'text'})`

Comment: If i change to { responseType : 'text' }, I get the error "ERROR in src/app/book.service.ts(28,61): error TS2322: Type '"text"' is not assignable to type '"json"'." while compiling.

Comment: If you have used postman, can you please test the api in postman and post the response metadata.  That would be helpful to sort it out

Comment: access-control-allow-credentials →true
access-control-allow-origin →chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
content-length →24
content-type →text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
date →Thu, 16 May 2019 08:39:53 GMT
vary →Origin

Comment: response is : Book created with ID =45, where the id is primary key.

Comment: There it is, the return content type is text/plain. Can you try setting the response content type to application/json in the backend. No need to make the {responseType: 'text'} changes I suggested

Comment: Also `return this._http.post<Book>(this._postBooksUrl, body, httpOptions)` change it to `return this._http.post<any>(this._postBooksUrl, body, httpOptions)`

Comment: return this._http.post(this._postBooksUrl, book,{'responseType':'text'}) this works, but does this not restrict me pass other header options?

Comment: also I removed the Json.stringify()

Comment: @manjosh, you can still pass on your headers like `this._http.post<Book>(this._postBooksUrl, body, {responseType: 'text'; headers:httpOptions})`

Comment: @manjosh, If it worked, please mark the answer as correct, I will update the answer with your comments too